# Generic type parameter gives error, but wildcard type parameter does not

Tags: java, generics

The following types do not produce any compiler warnings:

```
public abstract Class<? extends BaseType> getSubclassType();
@Override
    public Class<SubType> getSubclassType() {
        return SubType.class;
    }
```

The following concrete method produces an unchecked cast compiler warning:

```
public abstract <T extends BaseType> Class<T> getSubclassType();

    @Override
    public  <T extends BaseType> Class<T> getSubclassType() {
        return (Class<T>) SubType.class;
    }
```

Is there any way to define the method with a generic type parameter (in the base class) and return the appropriate concrete type in the subclass without generating compiler warnings? Obviously, both examples that I've given above will work just fine, I just want to know if there is a more correct way to define the method. Note: I do know that I could do the following:

```
public abstract class BaseClass <T extends BaseType> 
public abstract Class<T> getSubclassType();
```

I am wondering if there is a way to define the method header itself, with a generic type, without defining it on the class. And also, I am curious why the wildcard declaration does not give and warnings but the "equivalent" generic declaration does.

Comment: In the wildcard example, `SubType.class` is Necessarily of type `Class<SubType>`. However, in the generic one, there's no way for the program to implicitely know if `SubType.class` Really extends `BaseType` so it gives a warning. As for a way to avoid that, I can't think of any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are very different.

In the first one, the caller does not know what the type argument of the `Class` that is returned is. The caller cannot make any assumptions about what that type argument is, other than it extends `BaseType`. The method can choose to return a `Class` whose type argument is any subtype of `BaseType` it wants, unknown to the caller.

In the second case, the method is a generic method and `T` is a type variable of the method. That means that the caller can choose `T` to be whatever it wants, and expect the method to magically work with `T` being that type. Notably, the method does not receive any arguments, which means the method does not have any information at runtime regarding what `T` is at all, and must nevertheless somehow figure out how to return a `Class<T>`. Obviously, this is impossible, unless it always returns `null`.

Comment: Isn't example two type erased to 
    public  Class<BaseType> getSubclassType() {
        return (Class<BaseType>) SubType.class;
    }

Comment: @KyleM: The erasure for both are the same: `public  Class getSubclassType() {
        return SubType.class;
    }`, but that's irrelevant. What the caller can do in generics with each type signature is very different.

Comment: Makes perfect sense actually. To rephrase (just for my understanding, your explanation was great).... In the second example, the caller can specify any type they want, and expect the method to return that type. However that is obviously impossible given that it does not have that type information at runtime. Conversely, in my first example, the caller only know that the type returned extends BaseType; and cannot make additional assumptions about the type.